# How to download/load new scene contents based on a generated link from web?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, mobile, tablet

I would like to implement something that would resemble a mobile game hub or a content player somehow. Let's assume I have a generated link and when I press it on phone/tablet it will take me to this app which in turn it will download the new contents from the web and loaded as a new scene. Without concerning ourselves with security aspects like registration/login or even payment at this stage, is it possible to achieve this kind of mobile app with Unity? Basically it's a welcome scene that would show the downloading/loading for the new scene contents based on a given web link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve the result via [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) or (newer option) [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/manual/index.html). Both allows you to deploy any content (excluding script codes) after your app has been built. Popular use cases:

- Download new content from web (as in your request)
- Direct Modding support in-game (yes it is also possible, but distributing skeleton project with deployment configured)
- Patching game outside of deployment platform (like Steam)

Take a note that Unity version used to build AssetBundle or Addressable must match EXACTLY the version you used for main application. Any mismatch will trigger hard to diagnose problems and strange debug logs.

Comment: Thanks PiotrK. To make iOS/Android recognize the generated link to open the unity app would be the only missing part here